# Cannot import local python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one script that contains a function I want to use in another, i.e.

```
def main():
    def ex(a,b):
        return a+b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Whenever I import this script into another, I get the error "module 'script' has not attribute 'ex'" :

```
import script

script.ex(4,5)
```

Comment: `ex` is not exposed and can't be imported like that.  `main` is, however, if that helps illustrate what is exported.

Comment: In other words: you have to put `def ex()` at the same scope/indentation level of `def main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is right, the function `ex()` is a local function which is known only in the scope of the function `main()`.  If you import that module, it will contain the function `main()` and if you call that, *within* it, while this function is executed, there will exist the function `ex()`.  As soon as the function `main()` terminates, the function `ex()` will cease to exist.

You probably were under the impression that functions have a (module-)global scope which is not the case in Python.

You can change your code in many ways to avoid the error.  The most obvious would be to define `ex()` on the module level (i. e. no *inside* the `main()` function):

```
def main():
    # do whatever
    pass

def ex(a,b):
    return a+b
```

Another option would be to *return* the local function:

```
def main():
    def ex(a,b):
        return a+b
    return ex
```

Then the importing program could do this:

```
import script

ex = script.main()
print(ex(4, 5))
```

And there are lots of other ways to achieve what you want.  Since you didn't tell us why this `ex()` is in this `main()` etc. we can only guess which way is the best for you.

Comment: Yes that was the impression I was under. I'm guessing it is not a good practice to call module.main() after it is imported?

Comment: Well, depends.  I've never seen it named `main()` then, but some modules need to be initialized somehow after importing.  Most prominently graphical libraries come to mind, e. g. `import SomeWindowsLib` and then `winServer = SomeWindowsLib.init()` or `….getWinServer()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your code into something like this:

```
def main(a,b):
    def ex(a,b):
        return a+b
    return ex(a,b)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to elaborate something like this would happen:

```
import script
script.main(1,2)
```

The problem is that ex() is defined under the scope of the main function. You won't be able to access it from the outside directly.

Answer (score -1):

To call the function `ex()` as you're trying to call it, you have to encapsulate it in a class within script.py or whatever file `script` exists in. So in your case, script.py should look like this:

`class Script:
     def ex(a,b):
         return a+b`

and in the file where you want to use script:

`script = new Script()
 script.ex(4, 5)`

Hope this helps.